# how to unbind and bind again

Tags: events, bind, jquery

```
$("#archive").click(function(event){
        /*do something*/
});

$('#archive2').unbind('click',event);
```

i have this click function that I unbind.  however, i want to bind it again when i click a certain button.

```
$("#archive").bind("click",event);
```

im  using this code to bind again, however it doesn't seem to work. any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: it's better to tag questions with a programming language or technology name, and only after add some specific tags

Answer (score 6):

You have to keep a reference to the function (instead of passing an anonymous function):

```
function handler() {
    // do something
}

$("#archive").click(handler); // bind the first time
$("#archive").unbind('click', handler); // unbind
$("#archive").click(handler); // bind again
```

Not sure what is `event` in your case, but if it is the `event` object passed to the event handler then it does not make sense to pass it to `unbind` and `bind`.

Answer (score 3):

As of [jQuery 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for all your event handler binding:

```
var handler = function() {
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
};
$('#foo').on('click', handler);
$('#foo').off('click', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a boolean value and an `if` statement in the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a handler to the function so you can bind/unbind from it. (Also allows you to bind/unbind specific events handlers within the same event:

```
var handler = function() {
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
};
$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
$('#foo').unbind('click', handler);
```

(used from http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ )

Comment: @tep: You're welcome! Looks like you're new here- welcome to the community; remember to mark an answer and vote up any useful posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var closeHandle = function () {
      alert('close');        
};

function addClick() {       
         $("#btnTest").unbind('click').click(closeHandle);          
}
```